# unable to send build for android after adding cloudinary lib

Tags: codenameone, cloudinary

I just found out that whenever I tried to send a build to the server I recieve ana error This is the output error :

Note: there were 4 references to unknown classes.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
Note: there were 41 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
      (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
Note: there were 29 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Note: there were 5 class casts of dynamically created class instances.
      You might consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes and/or
      their implementations (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclasscast)
Warning: there were 124 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 4.44 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

  > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

Comment: The names of the unresolved classes should be listed in the error log but you trimmed that out.

Comment: Good day sir:
The error log is quite long, this is what i could get from it,correct?direct me if I'm looking in the wrong direction:

Comment: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
 at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.awaitRethrowExceptions(Job.java:79)
 at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.transform(ProGuardTransform.java:209)

Comment: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
 at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:473)
 at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:233)

Comment: i think it all started after i included the cludinary lib in the project

Comment: That's way after the listing of the error, if you scroll up in the log you will see NOTE's and WARNING's from proguard that indicate the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround that I've found for this so far is to download and compile [codenameone-maven-plugin](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.codenameone/codenameone-maven-plugin) and in src\main\java\com\codename1\maven\ComplianceCheckMojo.java at method runProguard(int passNum) add

```
java.createArg().setValue("-dontwarn");
```

on the first pass. Then use the modified version of the plugin.